# docker-compose: Modify environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Given a `docker-compose.yml` file in version "2" and a running container. 
How to pass a modified environment variable specified in the .yml-file to the running container. Which `docker-compose` command needs to taken without rebuilding the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just run `docker-compose up` command again.

Comment: That sounds easy :-) Thanks.